# How do I prepare the following compound from diphenylmethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis

I am having trouble with the preparation of this product from diphenylmethane as a starting material. One of my thoughts was to attach the butene into the structure, but I don't see how it is viable. So I would like some suggestions on how to proceed, and also with the name of the compound (butenediphenylmethane?).

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be that reactant? You'd probably have much easier time starting from the ketone and then doing a wittig reaction...

Comment: Diphenylmethanes deprotonate readily with alkyllithium

Comment: @Waylander how would you introduce the double bond after a reaction with propyllithium?

Comment: I would react the lithiated diphenylmethan with DMF, workup to give the aldehyde and do a Wittig

Comment: I'm a little concerned that that the product is very easy to convert to the 1,1-diphenylalkene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a mechanism that I thought of (It's more theoretical than practical):

[image: mechanism]

Bromination in the first step will occur at the benzyl position due to a stable free radical. Sodium Propynide then adds more carbon atoms via the SN2 mechanism, which are then reduced with Lindlar's catalyst to give the *cis*-alkene.

The name of this compound should be (*Z*)-1,1-diphenylbut-2-ene, but as pointed out in the comments, the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) seems to be (*Z*)-but-2-ene-1,1-diyldibenzene (verified by ChemDraw)

Comment: Looks reasonable. Do you have a reference for the reaction with the sodium acetylide?

Comment: I couldn't find any papers, but [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/09%3A_Alkynes_-_An_Introduction_to_Organic_Synthesis/9.09%3A_Alkylation_of_Acetylide_Anions#:~:text=Acetylide%20anions%20are%20strong%20bases%20and%20strong%20nucleophiles.&text=Because%20the%20ion%20is%20a,elimination%20by%20the%20E2%20mechanism.) Is one source. Here's a similar reaction with [Sodium Acetylide](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv4p0117)

Comment: It would be a SN1 reaction rather than an SN2 reaction because of the stability of the diphenylmethyl carbocation. Also, E2 won't occur as there are no $\alpha$-H atoms in the substrate

Comment: You can't generate carbocations in such a strongly basic medium, so SN1 is a no-no. Your reaction is quite probably OK, but a very brief literature search suggests that using the Grignard + Cu(I) is more likely to work than attempting a direct SN2. cc @Waylander

Comment: (one example at e.g. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jm4010434 where it's TMS-acetylene instead of propyne).

Comment: Maybe hydrostannylate the propyne then do a Stille with the bromodiphenylmethane

Comment: @orthocresol would a Corey-House synthesis with [Lithium Dipropenyl Cuprate](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/182127) be a better alternative? (This would also remove the reduction step) I'm not that conversent with organometallics to follow Waylander's suggestion

Comment: I'm not sure if you can buy the stereochemistry (i.e. whether the vinyl anion is configurationally stable enough to be used directly in a synthesis). https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/419540 doesn't seem to sell well-defined isomers. I think your original suggestion of using an alkyne anion is better. That concept is fine, my original comment was just an extra tidbit, because sometimes some conditions work better than others.

Comment: Thanks @orthocresol. I updated the answer to change the mechanism from SN1 to SN2 (no carbocations in a basic medium).

Comment: (Z)-1,1-diphenylbut-2-ene is not the preferred IUPAC name.